# How to create a color bar with rows of text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I use flutter to create bar show in the screenshot below?

[image: 1]

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
          child: Text("CONTACT US",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
          child: SizedBox(
          child: Text("SOCIAL MEDIA", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
      ),
        )
    ),
    Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
          child: SizedBox(
          child: Text("NEWSLETTER", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
      ),
        )
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: you need to create a Row with 3 children, the 3 children will be a Column and the children of the column are your element.
Then you can Wrap all into one Container and give the prefered background.

Comment: Emanuel Developer, Do you have an example? Give me sample layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with something similar and adjust for your purpose and color:

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('sample'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 2000,
        color: Color(0xff808080),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Contact Us'),
                Row(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.phone),
                  Text('phone')]),
                Row(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.mail),
                  Text('info@test.it')]),
                Row(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
                  Text('unavailable')]),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Contact Us'),
                Icon(Icons.wrap_text_rounded),
                Icon(Icons.point_of_sale),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Newsletter'),
                Text('Susbcribe'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Emanuel Developer. Yes this works. Just curious do you know how to make it collapsable for phones?

Comment: it is the same you just need to adjust Container( height and width )

Comment: No! I do not think you understand. I am coding a website. I wonder if you know how to make it responsive for phone. So that the second column collapse under the first and the third collapse under the second.

Comment: yes you can wrap them with WRAP instead of ROW and you can also use as width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

Comment: I am sorry what you mention is confusing. Can you give me a visual example\? send it to camaronbrowne@gmail.com.  Are you saying remove all the internal row widgets and replace them with Wrap?

Comment: It is better to mark this question as "Solved" and open another one with the other question sir.

Comment: Emmanuel Developer. Can you explain how you wrap the rows so that the column could be responsive?

Comment: Emmanuel Developer I posted another question.